# JQuery Autocomplete: formatItem doesn't work

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

We've put frustrating hours into the attempt to get a remarkably simple script to work (and everyone else seems to be successful). Finally, we want to create an autosuggest textbox using JQuery that writes the value of a selected text into a hidden field, but this question isn't about that because even the first step fails (but working sample code regarding that is very welcome).

For some obscure reason, formatItem (and the other formatting functions) is not executed. What are we misunderstanding?

Any help is HIGHLY appreciated.

Here's the code (stripped of anything not needed for the example):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Why o why?</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var s = ["a", "b", "ab"];
        $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
            source: s,
            formatItem: function(row, i, n) { return "whatever" },
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Search <input id="txtSearch" type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

The autosuggest function as such is working in any browser, but no browser fires formatItem.

Comment: Hi there, not entirely sure how this formatItem is supposed to be triggered - this is not one of the events for jQueryUI's autocomplete. What exactly should formatItem do? Possibly the event you are needing to trigger here is 'open' which fires when the suggestion box appear. If I'm missing the point please provide further details. Thanks!

Comment: As Floyd Pink writes below, we have been on the wrong track, confusing the old plugin with the new bundled version. 'formatItem' should format the list of suggestions, but another newer method will do the same. Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those methods are all deprecated in the version that is bundled into the jQuery UI.
Check this [migration guide](http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/06/autocomplete-migration-guide) to learn more about how the old formatItem, formatMatch etc. could now be implemented.

Comment: This question is to promote this website?